# I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my dell inspiron 1545 and I can't get the wireless internet connection to work?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, internet, dell

I am very new to Ubuntu so please explain it in layman's terms.  I have found various threads that explain this problem and resolving it using a wired internet connection to download drivers.  I piggy back off my landlord's wifi so I don't have access to the router therefore I don't have access to a wired connection.  Is there any way I can get the correct downloads on a flash drive then put them onto the Ubuntu system?

Comment: It is possible. Can you include the output of `lspci` in your question.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that I am currently using for a wifi problem with a Dell Inspiron 9300 running 14.04.  (see my issue)

I have a wifi 'repeater/range extender' that provides an ethernet output (engenius erb9250).   I have that ethernet cable plugged into my Dell and that gets me to the internet.  But it tethers me to either the repeater location or the main wifi transmitter.

The repeater was configured when I had a functional wifi connection (different PC).

I have not tried connecting to a non-secured wifi -- the issue MIGHT be related to WPA type security.

My issue has not yet had a response.